# How to catch JNI/Java Exception?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have a JNI layer in my application. In some cases Java throws an exception. How can I get the Java exception in the JNI layer? I have the code something like as follows.

```
if((*(pConnDA->penv))->ExceptionCheck(pConnDA->penv))
{
    (*(pConnDA->penv))->ExceptionDescribe(pConnDA->penv); 
    (*(pConnDA->penv))->ExceptionClear(pConnDA->penv);
}
```

Will this block of code catch only JNI exceptions? Where will the exception description be logged in console (STDERR)? How do I get this into the buffer, so that I can pass it to my logger module?

Comment: check this: http://www.developer.com/java/data/exception-handling-in-jni.html

Comment: @raypixar: Your link seems to tell us barely more than the basics which are to be found in [the official JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: In [the question JNI Getting Exception Info - Attempted to read or write protected memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325860/jni-getting-exception-info-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory) you will find an example of how to call `toString` on the exception class (or object). Two things: • you **must** call `ExceptionClear` before almost anything else; • make sure you pass the exception object if appropriate, not the exception class object (the mistake made by that questioner).

Answer (score 37):

if you invoke a Java method *from* JNI, calling `ExceptionCheck` afterwards will return `JNI_TRUE` if an exception was thrown by the Java.

if you're just invoking a JNI function (such as `FindClass`), `ExceptionCheck` will tell you if that failed in a way that leaves a pending exception (as `FindClass` will do on error).

`ExceptionDescribe` outputs to stderr. there's no convenient way to make it go anywhere else, but `ExceptionOccurred` gives you a `jthrowable` if you want to play about with it, or you could just let it go up to Java and handle it there. that's the usual style:

```
jclass c = env->FindClass("class/does/not/Exist");
if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
  return;
}
// otherwise do something with 'c'...
```

note that it doesn't matter what value you return; the calling Java code will never see it --- it'll see the pending exception instead.

Comment: `ExceptionDescribe` prints to “a system error-reporting channel, such as `stderr`”, i.e. it is implementation dependent.

Comment: It does NOT work. Program has been crash at the first line. 
I have tried some case of try/catch, check Exception but still does not run.
What is solution for that ?

Comment: you *must* call `ExceptionClear()` if `ExceptionCheck() == JNI_TRUE` or the java code will throw the exception as soon as the control returns to the JVM

Comment: Assume, you have a C++nested call finding a ´env->ExceptionCheck()´ then you would prefer to throw a C++-exception and catch it in the immediate context of the JNI-method. Though, this exception cannot be specific. Or: Is there a way to ask for the type of java exception?

Answer (score 17):

This is a complement of the [Elliott Hughes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125673/938111). My answer provides a step-by-step example explaining how to catch exceptions and how to translate them between C++ and Java words using the [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) layer.

### Short answer

See the correct [Elliott Hughes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125673/938111).

### Reusable example

This answer and snippets are in public domain or in CC0 in order to ease reuse. All the source code here is C++03 backward compatible.

To reuse the above snippet do the following:

- Replace `mypackage::Exception` by your own C++ Exception.
- If the corresponding Java exception `my.group.mypackage.Exception` is not defined, then replace `"my/group/mypackage/Exception"` by `"java/lang/RuntimeException"`.

### Catch exceptions from Java

See also the [snippet on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cf4f3b6b1cb988f).

```cpp
void rethrow_cpp_exception_as_java_exception()
{
    try
    {
        throw; // This allows to determine the type of the exception
    }
    catch (const mypackage::Exception& e) {
        jclass jc = env->FindClass("my/group/mypackage/Exception");
        if(jc) env->ThrowNew (jc, e.what());
        /* if null => NoClassDefFoundError already thrown */
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
        jclass jc = env->FindClass("java/lang/OutOfMemoryError");
        if(jc) env->ThrowNew (jc, e.what());
    }
    catch (const std::ios_base::failure& e) {
        jclass jc = env->FindClass("java/io/IOException");
        if(jc) env->ThrowNew (jc, e.what());                          
    }                                                               
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        /* unknown exception (may derive from std::exception) */
        jclass jc = env->FindClass("java/lang/Error");
        if(jc) env->ThrowNew (jc, e.what());
    }
    catch (...) {
        /* Oops I missed identifying this exception! */
        jclass jc = env->FindClass("java/lang/Error");
        if(jc) env->ThrowNew (jc, "Unidentified exception => "
          "Improve rethrow_cpp_exception_as_java_exception()" );
    }
}
```

I thanks [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck) for contribution on the above C++ code.

### Adapt the JNI generated source code

The following file `Java_my_group_mypackage_example.cpp` use the above `rethrow_cpp_exception_as_java_exception()` function:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_my_group_mypackage_example_function1
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jlong value)
{
  try {
    /* ... my processing ... */
    return jlong(result);
  } catch(...) {
    rethrow_cpp_exception_as_java_exception();
    return 0;
  }
}
   
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_my_group_mypackage_example_function2
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jlong value)
{
  jstring jstr = 0
  try {
    /* ... my processing ... */
    jstr = env->NewStringUTF("my result");
  } catch(...) {
    rethrow_cpp_exception_as_java_exception();
  }
  return  jstr;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_group_mypackage_example_function3
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jlong value)
{
  try {
    /* ... my processing ... */
  } catch(...) {
    rethrow_cpp_exception_as_java_exception();
  }
}
```

### Corresponding Java code

File `example.java`

```java
package my.group.mypackage;

public class Example {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("my-DLL-name");
  }

  public Example() {
    /* ... */
  }

  private native int    function1(int); //declare DLL functions
  private native String function2(int); //using the keyword
  private native void   function3(int); //'native'

  public void dosomething(int value) {
    int result = function1(value);  
    String str = function2(value);  //call your DLL functions
    function3(value);               //as any other java function
  }
}
```

Note: "`my-DLL-name`" refers to the dynamic library produced from the above C/C++ code compiled. It can be `my-DLL-name.dll` on Windows or `my-DLL-name.so` on GNU/Linux/Unix.

### Steps

1. Generate `example.class` from `example.java` (using `javac` or maven or your favorite IDE Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ IDEA/...)
2. Generate C/C++ header file `Java_my_group_mypackage_example.h` from `example.class` using `javah`

Comment: Why is this a macro?  Completely unnecessary http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cf4f3b6b1cb988f  Additionally, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: Hi @MooingDuck Thanks for your coliru link :-) I have provided more details within my answer. Please tell me if my explanation is enough to understand the usage and customization of macro `CATCH_CPP_EXCEPTION_AND_THROW_JAVA_EXCEPTION`. My aim is to provide an answer to help as many people as possible. Thank you in advance for your help ;-) Cheers

Comment: Well my questions still hold.  I'll try to be clearer.  First, why a macro?  Macros are bad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives.  Secondly, the question is "How can I get[catch] the [currently thrown] Java exception in the JNI layer?"  Which your post does not actually answer. :/

Comment: First, thanks for the SO link about macro. But in our case, if you do not use this macro, you will have to duplicate the corresponding 30 lines within each function `Java_my_group_mypackage_example_function*`. Duplication might be worse than macro...  Secondly, I am sorry, I misunderstood the question :-/ My answer does not talk about C++ code (JNI) calling Java code and catching Java exception. I thought Java stuff should not be called from JNI layer...

Comment: In fact, this technique can be used without a macro and without duplication.  It can be put in a function, as I showed with the coliru link.  Check the `Java_group_package_class_function1` function in my code.

Comment: Very good trick! I have never seen that before. Thanks :-) I am updating my answer...

Comment: Here you do not answer the question.

Comment: Hi @EJP. Thank you for your feedback. I have refactored and clarified my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In the case, when the Java exception occurs in a nested C++ call, it's not done with a simple return, but you prefer to remove the intermediate stack levels according to the throw mechanism.

I solved this with a

```
class JavaException : public std::exception
{
};
```

Then in a nested call, where the exception is raised

```
void nestedMethod()
{
    env->CallVoidMethod(...); // Java call creating Exception
    if (env->ExceptionCheck())
    {
        throw JavaException();
    }
}
```

Finally returning to Java

```
void JNI_method(JNIenv *env)
{
    try
    {
        doComplexCall(); // --> nestedMethod()
    }
    catch(const JavaException&)
    {
        //coming from positive ExceptionCheck()
        return;
    }
}
```