# Possible to Use C headers in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, c++, c, xerces-c

I have a code in java and javascript to parse a XML and generate a html page. but the parser i'm using is in C. So i need to use those headers in java code. Is it possible?

since xerces parser i'm using is in C can i use the .hpp files imported into the Java code?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Wait, so you have Java/Javascript code that parses XML, but the parser is in C. So the parser is written in 3 languages?

Comment: You can write the parse logic in c and  then invoke it by jni.

Comment: You can use a native interface: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664899/wrapping-c-c-inside-java Java runs C under the hood, but of course, many of java's features under the hood are java-exclusive

Comment: Java has XML parsers of its own. Heck, one's even [provided for you in the JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/)!

Comment: What is your __specific__ problem? Questioners here are expected to _at least some_ research on their own.

Comment: Question is so confusing. Parser is written in 3 languages?? The parser well might be in Java as well. Please explain the question further.

Answer (score 0):

no. you can's use.c headers will not accepted by java.but you can use JNA. You do have to declare anythng.it automatically generates Java wrappers.
visit http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html