# JNI Getting Exception Info - Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm using the following code to try and obtain a class RWException (which extends Exception) in java so that I can call a method "getCode()" to retrieve an error code (int) and handle the error properly.  I went through the JNI docs and created the following code...  problem is I am getting an AccessViolation exception when I attempt to call the parameterless method getCode().  I get a valid handle for the class and the method id I am looking for.

```
jstring o = (jstring)envLoc->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls, mid, jstrUser, jstrPass, jstrGroup);
jthrowable exc = envLoc->ExceptionOccurred();

if (exc) {
    // Get the class
    jclass mvclass = env->GetObjectClass( exc );
    // Get method ID for method
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(mvclass, "getCode", "()I");
    // Call the method      
    jint code  =  env->CallIntMethod(mvclass, mid);
}
```

This code gives me an exception while debugging inVS.NET w/ the following info:

Attempted to read or write protected memory

**UPDATE**
Here is the java method I wish to invoke via JNI code above:

```
public int getCode() {
    return code;
}
```

Both the mvclass and mid objects are instantiated properly and should function unless I am missing something.

**UPDATE 2**

If I run the following code the toString() method works using the same concept:

```
jstring o = (jstring)envLoc->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls, mid, jstrUser, jstrPass, jstrGroup);
exc = envLoc->ExceptionOccurred();
if (exc) {

    envLoc->ExceptionClear();

    // Get the class
    jclass exccls = envLoc->GetObjectClass(exc);

    // Get method ID for methods 
    jmethodID getCodeMeth = envLoc->GetMethodID(exccls, "getCode", "()I");

    jmethodID getMsgMeth = envLoc->GetMethodID(exccls, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

    jstring obj = (jstring)envLoc->CallObjectMethod(exccls, getMsgMeth);
    String^ toString = JStringToCliString(obj);

    // this is where the access violation occurs
    jint jcode  =  envLoc->CallIntMethod(exccls, getCodeMeth);
    int code = jcode;
}
```

So, the toString() method returns the full class name of the object and it's the correct RWException object.  The method outlined in the first update getCode() is public, etc... so not sure why it gives a memory access violation error.

Comment: Exception is easy try catch and done.

Comment: the exception is occuring on the java side... which throws an exception of type RWException which I then try and trap via the ExceptionOccurred() method.I then need the code from the RWException object via the getCode() method - in java it would be along hte lines of int code = oRWexception.getCode();

Comment: Yeah, the exception is occured because it's not properly catch

Comment: @RomanC It is often necessary to propagate the exception and not catch it internally.  If every exception is caught inside the block where it's thrown, then the entire point of exceptions would be lost.

Comment: How is your `getCode` method declared?  Could it be that it's `protected` instead of `public`?

Comment: @AleksG Propogate or no propogate is not decide by you.

Comment: @RomanC it's decided by the person who is writing the code.  The OP is catching the exception - and he's question is exactly about handling it.  He just happens to be doing it in a native method.

Comment: @AleksG So what you able to propogate it to the native method?

Comment: @AleksG I added the method sig to the original post...  it's a very basic method.

Comment: @RomanC - yes, it's required of me to handle the exception which has additional information that is required for me to display the appropriate message. I don't want to argue whether it's in good coding taste or not as I can't change the java code anyhow.

Comment: Did you make sure that you are not running out of local references by calling `DeleteLocalRef()` whenever you're done with them?

Comment: Hey @Samuel, well, I don't have much code so running out of local references shouldn't be an issue. Plus, the toString method works properly as you can see in my 2nd update.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it work if you access the "code" field directly?

Comment: I tried that and it seemed to work... I read another post that said it was solved by marking the field as private and for some reason that resolved the issue.  the "code" field is private.  I setup a really simple example and can duplicate the problem, wish you could post zip files on here...

Comment: Well, actually, what worked is I didn't get an exception, but the code is always returned as 0 - when in java it is not set to 0...

Comment: @AleksG: I couldn’t find the reference, but I believe that `protected` / `public` is not an issue, as I recall that JNI does not enforce access control, neither for fields nor for methods. (It is clear from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html#wp725) that private members are accessible via JNI.)

Comment: It is stated in [the documentation of JNI Exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp17707) which JNI functions may be called before `ExceptionClear` — `getMethodID` is not among them. Therefore your original code, whether or not it sometimes seemed to work, was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// exc is the exception object
exc = envLoc->ExceptionOccurred();

...

// exccls is the exception CLASS
jclass exccls = envLoc->GetObjectClass(exc);
jmethodID getCodeMeth = envLoc->GetMethodID(exccls, "getCode", "()I");

...

// CallIntMethod(jobject instance, jmethodID method)
jint jcode = envLoc->CallIntMethod(exccls, getCodeMeth);
// exccls is the CLASS, not the object
// so correct would be:
jint jcode = envLoc->CallIntMethod(exc, getCodeMeth);
```

Oh wow.

And the compiler doesn't complain about this because every `jclass` is a `jobject`, just like `jstring`.

Comment: and BOOM! YOU   ARE   THE  MAN!!!  worked like a charm. Yes, compiler totally didn't complain. In fact, it was giving me back the method id's and everything - details... details... lol.  Thanks a ton my "main" man lol

Answer (score 2):

The only possible issue I can see in your code is that you are calling a method while an exception is still propagating. `envLoc->ExceptionOccurred()` gives you the exception object but you still have to actually catch it with `envLoc->ExceptionClear()`.

Comment: Ur right... I switched the method call from getCode to toString and the code above works fine... not sure what that means  then ...

Comment: What happens if you add a null check for `getCodeMeth`?

Comment: it passes as it's *not* null... so not sure why it's blowing up. very strange indeed...

Comment: It is stated at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp17707 which JNI functions may be called before `ExceptionClear` — `getMethodID` is not among them.

Answer (score 1):

You have no error checking in this code. You need to check the result of every JNI operation: GetObjectClass(), GetMethodID(), CallXXXMethod() ... For example you are assuming the class has a getCode() method, and calling it without checking that.

Comment: I have checked via the IDE debugger - all return values from GetObjectClass(), GetMethodID() are *not* null as stated in the original post...

The CallIntMethod(xxx, xxx) doesn't even return - it blows up in the JNI.h calls with the Access Violation exception. Also, envLoc is valid as well.