# Catch exception in Android NDK C++ code

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to catch an error in native C++ code on Android. According to the docs FindClass returns NULL when class name cannot be find. But I got `FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fake/class` and execution never reaches the if statement.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

extern "C"
void Java_com_example_MainActivity_testError(JNIEnv *env, jobject) {
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("fake/class");
    // never gets here
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Also this exception skips the try-catch block and crashes the app. My Java code:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

public native void testError();

...
try {
    testError();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // exception never get cought
}
```

Also I use `cppFlags '-fexceptions'`. Is there a proper way to catch this exception or recover from it so the app does not crash?

Comment: From: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#FindClass   THROWS: NoClassDefFoundError: if no definition for a requested class or interface can be found.  JNI has methods to see if a Java exception is being thrown and deal with it.  The Java exception does not "become active" until the JNI method returns.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is not derived from java.lang.Exception but from java.lang.Error   That's why your exception is not being caught.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html

Comment: Since you mention the `-fexceptions` flag, don't confuse Java and C++ exceptions - they're completely separate beasts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to prevent native code from crashing on FindClass, etc. you have to use this code after every JNI call:

```
bool checkExc(JNIEnv *env) {
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe(); // writes to logcat
        env->ExceptionClear();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Actually, ExceptionClear() stops the crash. I have found the code on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777516/2424777

Second, to be sure to catch all crashes from native code, you have to use this try-catch. Credits @Richard Critten Also use it on all native function calls:

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    } catch (Error | Exception ignore) { }
}
```

And cppFlags '-fexceptions' has nothing to do it so you can remove it.

Comment: You have saved my day, wish I could upvote x10, Am using the first option and working well. Is there a way to make it log in the `Error` category of Android studio logcat? because it's logging in the `Info` category which has too much logs and finding becomes difficult.

Comment: it helped me a lot

Comment: ExceptionDescribe()  still prints to logcat (at the debug level) in android 11.