# How do we can programmatically restart android app after fatal crash

Tags: java, android, service, java-native-interface

I have fatal crash in third party library which use JNI. I want to do auto restart application fall. How do I programmatically restart an Android App ?
I have tried to create background service monitoring app health and trying to start the app. However, as of Android 11 Google has restricted doing that: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android: Handle Application Crash and start a particular Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829955/android-handle-application-crash-and-start-a-particular-activity)

Comment: It works only for Java Exception. If cpp code throw exception Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler doesn't catch and app fall.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment due to low reputation points :(  so i am writing here.
You might check this other question on how to catch the exception generated in your c++ code from [@kosev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2424777/kosev) at this link [Catch exception in Android NDK C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40163930/9015853)

---

You should change the question title to include the fact that wou want to catch the exception raised from c++ code and not Java/Kotlin code.