# C++ signal handler can't notify Java side

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I have the following CPP code. What I want to do is when an error occurs in my native side, I will notify Java about the error. I used [How can I catch SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) and get a stack trace under JNI on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083154/how-can-i-catch-sigsegv-segmentation-fault-and-get-a-stack-trace-under-jni-on) as reference.

```
static JavaVM* g_JVM = NULL;
static jobject  g_thejavaobject  = NULL;

void InitializeNativeSide(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jobject object)
{
    env->GetJavaVM(&g_JVM);
    g_thejavaobject = env->NewGlobalRef(object);
}

// this executes in another thread running in parallel with UI thread
void StartExecuting(JNIEnv *_env, jclass) {
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = SignalErrorHandler;
    sa.sa_flags   = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);

    // native starts executing here. after a while, a SEGFAULT is encountered
    // triggering SignalErrorHandler()
    ...
}

void SignalErrorHandler(int signal, siginfo_t *si, void *arg)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    g_JVM->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    jclass myClass = env->FindClass("com/company/MyClass");
    jmethodID myMethod = env->GetMethodID(myClass, "nativeCrashed", "()V" );
    env->CallVoidMethod(g_thejavaobject, myMethod);

    env->DeleteLocalRef(myClass);
}
```

Everything works fine but the call to myClass.nativeCrashed() does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really think it's safe to make Java calls in a signal handler?  That is not going to work.  The **only** function calls that can be safely made from a signal handler are async-signal-safe one listed at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
void SignalErrorHandler(int signal, siginfo_t *si, void *arg)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    g_JVM->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    jclass myClass = env->FindClass("com/company/MyClass");
    jmethodID myMethod = env->GetMethodID(myClass, "nativeCrashed", "()V" );
    env->CallVoidMethod(g_thejavaobject, myMethod);

    env->DeleteLocalRef(myClass);
}
```

That will not work for at least two fundamental reasons.

First, only async-signal-safe functions may be called from within a signal handler.  The POSIX-specified list can be found at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03.

No Java JNI call is async-signal-safe.

Second, [the Java JVM uses `SIGSEGV` internally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/troubleshoot/handle-signals-and-exceptions.htm#JSTGD356) - getting a `SIGSEGV` is not necessarily fatal:

> **Signals Used in Oracle Solaris, Linux, and macOS**
>
> ...
>
> `SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGPIPE, SIGILL` These signals are used in
>   the implementation for implicit null check, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I appreciate it. By the way, the link in my post claims that he was able to call java from his signal handler. Now im confused.

Comment: @user1506104 Read the POSIX documentation I linked:  "when a signal interrupts an unsafe function or equivalent ... and the signal-catching function calls an unsafe function, **the behavior is undefined**." The problems are only specified to happen at certain times, and then the results are "undefined behavior".  In short, it can *appear* to work - until it fails.  It's similar to overrunning an array - it might "work", but it's still wrong.  And it can fail.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @user1506104 Thanks for that.  I had to learn this the hard way, too.  This question is also relevant, as the questioner was doing something similar:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547199/art-prevents-any-java-calls-from-jni-during-native-signal-handling/34553070#34553070