# Handle exceptions occured in native library in Xamarin.Android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In my Xamarin.Android app I use native library loaded like `JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("my_library")` App crashes when any exception occured in this library.

How can I avoid it - safety handle or ignore those exceptions?

Comment: You should handle them completely within your shared library (C++ exceptions, etc..), because you can not "catch" them with ART and thus Mono as you can not perform JNI callbacks into Java when in a signaled state. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547199/art-prevents-any-java-calls-from-jni-during-native-signal-handling

Comment: As a side question, is your shared library dependent upon running in an Java context, i.e. is there are reason you are not using Mono/.Net's native interop?

Comment: I use SIP library (linphone) in my app. Core of library is native libraries + some c# wrappers.

Comment: Yes, I know libLinphone, I use it directly in Xamarin.iOS|Android via .NEt interop.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanded... 
I call native libLinphone functions from c# wrapper via [DllImport] - as implemented in official Xamarin example project. Are there another ways to use this library?

Comment: Why are you using java&#39;s loadlibrary function then?

Comment: I can't call native functions via wrapper (DllImport) without prior execute `JavaSystem.LoadLibrary` - exception occurring and app crushing