# App crashed when (*env)->FindClass(env, "package/WrongClass");

Tags: java, android, exception, android-ndk

Just run this small jni function and exception was thrown, because I specifically pointed out the wrong class, solely for the test.:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_org_package_Native_fc(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {
    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "package/WrongClass");
    // i want work , dont crush me ... What condition i can use or exception catching or ...
}
```

How to catch exceptions INSIDE c code and work further, rather than an entire APK application crashing.

Comment: Is there something meaningful in logcat? What exact crash you get?

Comment: Notfoundclass exception, ... And other java exception.. (Dont remember now). But how to stop exception, before java , in c code....

Comment: Look for `env->ExceptionClear()`

Comment: See especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289742/192373